# Ajax form submission behaviour

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have an odd Ajax problems (I am not very good at it, so all problems are odd..)
I have a form that requires heavy validation (there are large files involved) so I decided to implement a small Ajax method to validate while the user waits.
The problem is that, while the Ajax call is being made correctly, the I cannot manage to get the form to post to the correct php file upon completion of the verification.

The form looks like this;

```
<form id="initialForm" method="post" action="/files/processing.php">
...    
<input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/> 
</form>
```

and the javascript looks like this:

```
$(function() {
    var request;
    $("#initialForm").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var validated = false;
        //flush pending requests
        if (request){request.abort;}
        $.ajax({
            url: 'test.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: $('#initialForm').serialize()
        }).success(function (response){
            var errorMessages = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log(errorMessages['errorTest']);
            validated = checkErrorMessages(); //true/false
        }).done(function (response) {
             $('#initialForm').unbind('submit');
            if (validated)
               $('saveForm').click();
        }).fail(function () {
        });
    });
});
```

After logging the message contained in the `errorMessages` JSON object to the console, the form does not submit to "files/processing.php". 
I am sure its a small thing, but I cannot get it to work.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

You have prevented the form's submit initally. Hence you have to submit it after you are logging your errors.

```
$(function() {
    var request;
    $("#initialForm").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var validated = false;
        //flush pending requests
        if (request){request.abort;}
        $.ajax({
            url: 'test.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: $('#initialForm').serialize()
        }).done(function (response) {  
            var errorMessages = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log(errorMessages['errorTest']);
            if(checkErrorMessages()) { //validate fields
                $('#initialForm').unbind('submit'); //unbind submit if valid
                $('#saveForm').click(); //submit form
            }
        }).fail(function () {
        });    
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**  You have to unbind the submit event only when the form validation is success and not otherwise. You can either use .success() or .done() function(both does the same job). But it is preferable to use done(), as success() would get deprecated from [version 1.8](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). I have updated the above code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks rahki4110..I had already tried that, but It results in an infinite loop of submissions..any ideas?

Comment: Ya. Sorry overlooked it. Updated the answer.

Comment: Cheers rahki4110! ajax and javascript are one of those things I am quite sure I will NEVER get..

Comment: rahki4110, I've edited the code now (the post as well) and added the rest of my required functionalities. However, if the checks fail once, then clickin on the submit button submits the form without any further checks..any ideas? I have tried unbinding the submit event at different stages to no avail.

Comment: @horacv: Edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: cheers rakhi4110..I am just a bit puzzled, because it used to be that I did not need to unbind the events..I must be missing something because now I have to click once for the ajax and once again to submit..odd indeed..

Comment: @horacv: I dont think so. This code works. check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2DsF/)